# Extending extruder heater and thermistor wires

Tags: hotend

I wanted to extend the E3D V6's extruder heater and the thermistor wires. Is it ok to solder extension wires or does it have to be crimp only! Also are regular wires ok or does it have to be some special cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soldering is fine, both for the thermistor wires as for the heater.

The wires don't need to be particularly special, though there are some things you should keep in mind:

- Current. The heater can draw up to 3-4A, the wires need to be able to handle this. The wires for the thermistor can be thinner.
- Flexibility. The hotend (presumably) moves, so the wires should be able to withstand frequent movement. Use stranded (rather than solid) wire.

Comment: Thanks! And soldering is fine for the thermistor wires too? I've worked with thermocouples and extending those wires by soldering is a strict no-no

Comment: Yes. Thermocouples work on a different principle from thermistors.